# Javascript : workers doesn't do anything onmessage

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm trying to create a reminder at a certain date. For that i'm using web-workers with active waiting.

Main.js :

```
function reminder(message, api) {
  var worker = new Worker("./worker.js");
  var mesCore = message.body.substr(message.body.indexOf(" ") + 1);
  worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    api.sendMessage("Ding dong " + mesCore, message.threadID);
};
worker.postMessage(mesCore);
}
```

worker.js

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

// reach this line when create worker

onmessage = function(e) {
    // never reach this line
    console.log(e.data);
    var origin = new Date(e.data);
    cron.schedule("* * *", function() {
        var now = new Date();
        if (
            origin.getFullYear() == now.getFullYear() &&
            origin.getMonth() == now.getMonth() &&
            origin.getDate() == now.getDate()
        ) {
            postMessage('message');
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately the worker never reach the onmessage content. I tried this.onmessage and self.onmessage but it doesn't work. I also tried with "addEventListener" but doesn't work either.
I'm doing this in javascript because the api that I'm using is in javascript so I have no choice.

Thank you if can't help me find a solution

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to figure out the issue? Without additional context to the question, I wouldn't expect the first line of `worker.js` to even work. `require` is a Node.js builtin, and is not something that would work in a browser, not even a web worker.

Comment: In fact no because I don't really understand how all of it works. But debugger in this particular case will only show me that I don't enter in the onmessage when receiving a message. About the require, I used a custom function before that and I had the exact same result